# Retrieving value of prop is returning null or undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question component with 4 clickable answers, I'm trying to pass a value to a prop ie

```
data-correct={"spice"}
```

This is one of the props in my answer component.  When I'm rendering the answers, I'm passing a value of true to this prop if it's the correct answer to the current question.

At this point I'm just trying to retrieve the value of this prop on click  ie

```
answerClick (e) {
    let tag = e.target.dataset.correct.value;
    console.log(tag)
}
```

I'm getting a value of null or undefined with this every time.  I've tried various targeting methods like ..

```
e.target.getAttribute('data-correct')
e.target.dataset.correct.value
e.target.attributes.getNamedItem('data-correct').value
```

I'm not sure what the issue is

For reference here is the relevant code in it's entirety

```js
      constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        showStartButton: true,
        commence: false,
        level: 1,
        question: null,
        answerSet: {
            a1: null,
            a2: null,
            a3: null,
            a4: null
        },
        correctAnswer: {
            a1: true,
            a2: null,
            a3: null,
            a4: null
        },
        score: 0
    }
    this.startGame = this.startGame.bind(this);
    this.hoverEnter = this.hoverEnter.bind(this);
    this.hoverLeave = this.hoverLeave.bind(this);
    this.answerClick = this.answerClick.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount() {
    // Change game state based on level

    let tempQ;

    switch (this.state.level) {

        case 1:
        tempQ = "What is the name of the main protagonist in all of the Legend of Zelda games?";
        this.setState({answerSet:{
            a1: "Link",
            a2: "Zelda",
            a3: "Gerudo",
            a4: "Zant"
        }});
        break;

        case 2:
        tempQ = "Link has reincarnated under this title.";
        this.setState({answerSet:{
            a1: "Vanquisher",
            a2: "Ruler of the Realm",
            a3: "Hero of Time",
            a4: "The Champion"
        }});
        break;

        case 3:
        tempQ = "What is the name of the clan of females theives that Ganondorf was born into?";
        this.setState({answerSet:{
            a1: "The Deku",
            a2: "The Hylians",
            a3: "The Twili",
            a4: "The Gerudo"
        }});
        break;

        case 4:
        tempQ = "Who does Link rescue from the belly of Lord Jabu-Jabu?";
        this.setState({answerSet:{
            a1: "Zelda",
            a2: "Princess Ruto",
            a3: "Impa",
            a4: "Saria"
        }});
        break;

        case 5:
        tempQ = "The recurring legendary sword that Link aquires in the series has many names.  Which is not an official name of the sword?";
        this.setState({answerSet:{
            a1: "The Sword of Time",
            a2: "The Master Sword",
            a3: "The Sword of Old",
            a4: "The Sword that Seals the Darkness"
        }});
        break;

        default:
        console.log("somethings broke")
        break;
    }

    this.setState({question: tempQ});
}

startGame() {
    this.setState({showStartButton: false, commence: true});
    console.log(this.state.answerSet)
}

answerClick (e) {
    let tag = e.target.dataset.correct.value;
    console.log(tag)
}

hoverEnter () {
    this.setState({classes: ["Question", "hover"]})
}

hoverLeave () {
    this.setState({classes: "Question"})
}

render() {
    
    return(
        <div className={classes.GameStage}>
            <div className={classes.QuestionContainer}>
                <h1>The Legend of Zelda Trivia</h1>

                {this.state.showStartButton ? 
                    <button className={classes.StartButton} onClick={this.startGame}>START</button>
                : null }

                {this.state.commence ?
                    <Timer />
                : null }

                {this.state.commence ? 
                    <Question q={this.state.question} />
                : null }
            </div>

            {this.state.commence ?
                <div className={classes.AnswerContainer}>
                    <Answer 
                        onClick={this.answerClick}
                        onMouseEnter={this.hoverEnter} 
                        onMouseLeave={this.hoverLeave} 
                        correct={this.state.correctAnswer.a1}>
                        {this.state.answerSet.a1}
                    </Answer>
                    <Answer 
                        onClick={this.answerClick}
                        onMouseEnter={this.hoverEnter} 
                        onMouseLeave={this.hoverLeave} 
                        correct={this.state.correctAnswer.a2}>
                        {this.state.answerSet.a2}
                    </Answer>
                    <Answer 
                        onClick={this.answerClick}
                        onMouseEnter={this.hoverEnter} 
                        onMouseLeave={this.hoverLeave} 
                        correct={this.state.correctAnswer.a3}>
                        {this.state.answerSet.a3}
                    </Answer>
                    <Answer 
                        onClick={this.answerClick}
                        onMouseEnter={this.hoverEnter} 
                        onMouseLeave={this.hoverLeave} 
                        correct={this.state.correctAnswer.a4}>
                        {this.state.answerSet.a4}
                    </Answer>
                </div>
            : null }
        </div>
```

Here is the answer component

```js
import React from 'react';

import classes from './Answer.css';

const answer = (props) => (
    <div         
        className={classes.Answer}
        onMouseEnter={props.onMouseEnter} 
        onMouseLeave={props.onMouseLeave}
        onClick={props.onClick}
        data-correct={props.correct}>
        {props.children}
    </div>
)

export default answer;
```

Comment: What is `Answer`? Does it correctly pass all properties to a DOM node it supposedly renders?

Comment: If I just console.log('working') in answerClick(), it works fine..  I'll edit and add the answer component

Comment: Well, `this.state.answerSet.a1` *is* `null` in your code. You are not showing how the value changes at any time.

Comment: I have just omitted the logic..  I'll add it

Comment: There should be no `.value` after `dataset.correct`, but the `getAttribute` way should also work. If not, idk what to say. Try inspecting your DOM tree?

Comment: You are only updating `this.state.answerSet`, but never `this.state.correctAnswer`, so all those values (`correct={this.state.correctAnswer.a1}`, etc) continue to be `null`.

Comment: it still returns undefined even if i hard code something like correct="pirate"

Comment: As riv mentioned, it should be `e.target.dataset.correct` not `e.target.dataset.correct.value`.

Comment: @riv  I'm not sure how I missed what you said, I thought I had tried that before without using .value but it's working now.  Ty